# IE6 CSS tooltip not appearing

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I'm using a tooltip that works in FF, Chrome, and IE7-8, but in IE6 it doesn't appear. You can go to this page http://www.avaline.com/ Bags/ Eco-Friendly-Bags/R1500 and login with test2@gmail.com password:test02, then hit the "add to cart" button and hover over the question marks to see (or not see) the tooltips.

This is the relevant HTML and CSS:

```
<DIV class="oewBox" id="oewImpLocDiv" style="BACKGROUND-IMAGE: url(/images/img/org4.gif)">
<A class="tooltip" href="#"><SPAN class=""><STRONG>More than 2 imprint locations?</STRONG> Test </SPAN></A>
</DIV>

<style>
/* Rule from element "style" attribute */
element.style {
    BACKGROUND-IMAGE: url(/images/img/org4.gif)
}
/* Rule N°8 from inline stylesheet */
.oewBox {
    PADDING-RIGHT: 8px;
    PADDING-LEFT: 40px;
    PADDING-BOTTOM: 16px;
    MARGIN: 0px 0px 6px;
    PADDING-TOP: 6px;
    BORDER-BOTTOM: #ff7c14 3px solid
}
/* Rule N°7 from inline stylesheet */
.oewBox {
    BACKGROUND-POSITION: 0px 0px;
    BACKGROUND-IMAGE: none;
    BACKGROUND-REPEAT: no-repeat
}
/* Rule N°11 from /site/av-files/mainstyles.css */
A:active {
    COLOR: #3b88c4;
    TEXT-DECORATION: none
}
/* Rule N°10 from /site/av-files/mainstyles.css */
A:hover {
    COLOR: #000;
    TEXT-DECORATION: none
}
/* Rule N°9 from /site/av-files/mainstyles.css */
A:visited {
    COLOR: #3b88c4;
    TEXT-DECORATION: underline
}
/* Rule N°8 from /site/av-files/mainstyles.css */
A:link {
    COLOR: #3b88c4;
    TEXT-DECORATION: underline
}
/* Rule N°7 from /site/av-files/mainstyles.css */
A {
    COLOR: #3b88c4;
    TEXT-DECORATION: underline
}
/* Rule N°52 from inline stylesheet */
A.tooltip {
    BACKGROUND: url(/images/img/question.gif) no-repeat;
    FLOAT: right;
    WIDTH: 19px;
    HEIGHT: 20px
}
/* Rule N°54 from inline stylesheet */
A.tooltip:hover SPAN {
    BORDER-RIGHT: #ff7c14 1px solid;
    BORDER-TOP: #ff7c14 1px solid;
    DISPLAY: inline;
    BACKGROUND: #ffffff;
    BORDER-LEFT: #ff7c14 1px solid;
    COLOR: #000;
    BORDER-BOTTOM: #ff7c14 1px solid;
    POSITION: absolute
}
/* Rule N°53 from inline stylesheet */
A.tooltip SPAN {
    PADDING-RIGHT: 3px;
    DISPLAY: none;
    PADDING-LEFT: 3px;
    FONT-WEIGHT: normal;
    FONT-SIZE: 11px;
    PADDING-BOTTOM: 2px;
    MARGIN-LEFT: -245px;
    WIDTH: 230px;
    PADDING-TOP: 2px
}
</style>
```

Comment: Just as a side warning: make sure on all of your secure pages (https) that you reference all of your images using https as well, otherwise you'll get those nasty security warnings in IE.

Comment: I think I just have to fix the Truste image. Also, I fixed the tooltip in IE6 for the most part, but now my select elements are poking through what should be my top-layer a.tooltip:hover span elements. I fixed a problem similar to this by making my top-layer element into a table, but I still don't understand why that worked and I'd rather not have to resort to tables. I tried z-index:999 (with position declared), but that failed. This is ridiculously frustrating. heh.

Comment: To solve the problem I went back here: http://www.kollermedia.at/archive/2008/03/24/easy-css-tooltip/ , adjusted some values accordingly, and added an a.tooltip:hover selector. 

The futile z-index as applied to form elements like SELECT is a bug that I should be able to fix now although I really wish I didn't have to use javascript to do so. heh. I guess I have to, though, or use an iframe or tables (since that worked for me before although i don't see it mentioned online)

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion here. Might want to try qTip. It's a jQuery plugin that works great.

[qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/)

Comment: I'm tempted... I'm trying to minimize the amount of Javascript (and Javascript framework) usage where I can, though.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm...maybe try changing `class=tooltip` to `class="tooltip"`?  I don't know what `DOCTYPE` you are using, but the unquoted attribute might be causing a problem...

EDIT:
Did some more research, try this:

replace

```
A.tooltip:hover SPAN
```

with

```
A.tooltip:link:hover SPAN
```

Comment: Quotes are around each class and id, but when I copied from IETester they got chopped out. I fixed this above.

Answer (score 0):

First do this:

```
add an HREF to your A. href="#" or something
```

I would also implement the tooltips like this:

```
a.tooltip:hover span {
  background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
  border:1px solid #FF7C14;
  color:#000000;
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -245px;
}

a.tooltip {
  background:url("/images/img/question.gif") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  float:right;
  height:20px;
  width:19px;
  position: relative;
}

a.tooltip span {
  display:none;
  font-size:11px;
  font-weight:normal;
  padding:2px 3px;
  width:230px;
}
```

Comment: I tried out your CSS, but it also didn't work. I also tried setting the z-index of the span (with hover and without), and when that didn't work I removed "float:right" from a.tooltip, and replaced it with "padding-left:40px;padding-top:40px;display:block;" in an effort to make it visible without float. The tooltip still didn't show up though, so I guess float isn't the source of the problem.

Comment: add an HREF to your A. href="#" or something.

Answer (score 0):

This is never going to work as is.  Consider these two rules:

```
A.tooltip:hover SPAN {
    DISPLAY: inline;
}
A.tooltip SPAN {
    DISPLAY: none;
}
```

And ask yourself this: if the span isn't displaying, how could you hover over it?

Comment: You are incorrect. It isn't the span being hovered over, it is its parent. When the parent is hovered over, the child span element is displayed inline.

Comment: But the span is the only thing in the parent.  Without content, the parent will collapse and be un-hoverable.

Answer (score 0):

Some solid tips (I logged in and tested some of it):

- Add `zoom:1` to the span and the `A` tag's CSS.
- By default, position the span `relative`.

Also, the background on the spans is reading as transparent, so you either have an error in your CSS or something isn't being declared right.

Good luck dear!